# Visual Studio 2010 suddenly running a lot slower

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have been working on a C# Winforms project in VS2010 for about 3 months now, and everything has been running smoothly - until today!

VS2010 runs fine whilst coding, and when the project is Debugging that runs fine too.  However its the transition between these two phases that is the problem.  Whenever I start Debugging (or exit Debugging) VS2010 hangs for 30 seconds and the window shows 'Not responding' in the header for a while, before it then resumes working again.

Secondly, and whether or not this is related I do not know, but each day I backup my work as a compressed file, and because I'm contiunually adding code, the backup file increases in size a little every day.  Last night however, after saving my work I noticed the file size has been reduced by aprox 10% - yet there is nothing missing from my project.

Aside from the hangups being annoying and holding up development, I'm worried that something may be corrupted and dread the thought of losing this project.

Does anyone have any ideas what may have happened / be causing these hang ups switching to and from Debugging mode, and for this problem to literally have appeared 'overnight'.

Answer (score 0):

I found this hint elsewhere, and it worked for me

From the run command, run the following command:

devenv /resetsettings

This would reset the IDE back to first time use